# How to restrict _rev_info in cloudant result json

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, couchapp

I am using cloudant for my Project. Every time i update a document and fetch a document, the result JSON comes with { _rev_info : [...] } (contains 500+ rev history). how i restrict & fetch data without _rev_info in cloudant??

```
{ name: "test",
  "age":22,
  _revs_info: [
          { rev: '510-454.....',
            status: 'available' }, 
            {....}
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_revs_info is only be returned if you explicitly request it by passing [revs_info=true](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/document/common.html#get--db-docid) in the query string. If you don't require the revision history, just exclude that parameter.

Comment: Thank you @Will. its working after change revs_info:false.